# Cron pattern for multiple time with *AND*

Tags: linux, cron

I want to create a cron pattern for the expression `Every day at 7 PM, 8:30 PM and 9:45 PM`.

Is it possible to create one cron pattern for it or I will have to write 3 separate ones?

Comment: You'll need to create multiple cron jobs.

Comment: 3 separate ones

Comment: Hmm. Seems like I'll have to create 3 seperate ones. Thanks.

Comment: If you're flexible with the times and 7:30, 8:30, 9:30 would be acceptable, then you could use [30 19,20,21 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#30_19,20,21_*_*_*)

Answer (score 0):

With `cron` alone you would have to create 3 separate cron jobs. However, here's a possible workaround: you can create a single `cron` entry for 7 PM, such as:

```
0 19 * * * /folder/script
```

And then create a script that "sleeps" the time you need before calling the other commands at 8:30 PM and 9:45 PM, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup my_command_here &
#sleep until 8:30 PM - 90 minutes or 5400 seconds
sleep 5400
nohup my_command_2_here &
#sleep until 9:45 PM - 75 minutes or 4500 seconds
sleep 4500
nohup my_command_3_here &
exit
```